# Locate actual location of calc.exe or notepad.exe or ... in windows 10

Tags: windows, c++11

In the old version(s) of windows *calc.exe* and other default windows applications were located in `%SystemRoot%\system32\`

This was true for mspaint.exe/cacl.exe/notepad.exe and so on.

Now they are located in some obscure sub-folders of `%SystemRoot%\WinSxS\`, (and in some cases it is in 2 folders).

My [launcher app](https://github.com/FFMG/myoddweb.piger) could simply try and launch "calc.exe" but I would rather pass the full 'proper' path, (or should I?).

So my question is, how can I locate the actual location of those exes?

Comment: Why would you keep a list of paths specific to each Windows version if you can just use `"calc.exe"` and let WinAPI figure the rest out?

Comment: Internally I use `ShellExecuteEx` to launch the app, and simply calling `calc,exe` does not launch it, (the path is not resolved). Hence the reason I am looking for the full path.

Comment: Ooops, sorry, there was a typo there, `calc.exe` can be launched using `ShellExecuteEx`, (I had a rogue space). I wonder if it is the better way to launch those apps, and I guess I am still kind of curious how to locate the actual path of those executables.

Comment: Try `where calc` to print the path. I assume it to just iterate over the directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable. You can see what API calls `which` does with Sysinternals' Process Monitor.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the `where` command, +1

Answer (score 1):

As @a3f pointed out in the comments of the question, the `where` command can be used to find the path of an executable in the `%PATH%`. It can be used (e.g., in `cmd`) like this:

```
C:\>where calc
C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe
```

The `where` command itself can also be located:

```
C:\>where where
C:\Windows\System32\where.exe
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's what I ended up using in the end.